# Locking by name (mutex alternatives)

Tags: .net, multithreading

For locking by name is any alternative to using named Mutex?

The locking is for Web application to prevent performing an operation many times in parallel on resource with same name so I need to lock by name. Ie. its fine to perform that operation at same time on resources with different names. Name of resource is a string coming in url. Lets say that resource is just an entity.

Is named mutex best option for this? Not too heavy?

Comment: Why do you need a named mutex for locking a string? Seriously, just stick a normal mutex around it and you'll be good.  Named Mutex is for system wide locking across many processes.

Comment: What kind of resource are you protecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by heaviness you mean the performance impact, using a named mutex should be negligible compared to the cost of processing a web request in general.

I think that named mutex is a good option, since then you're independent of the way your service is hosted (whether it's single or multi process depends on the server, not on your service), especially if your service is a library potentially used by many web applications. Aside from being limited to one process, a `lock` also requires a shared object reference for locking, so you need a reference which is visible to all threads/requests, a problem which the mutex's name (which is known in advance) elegantly solves.

Having said that, when protecting a resource it's always better to protect the resource itself rather than an entry point to that resource. For example, if your service protects concurrent access to some parts of a database then it's better to use a DB transaction with an appropriate isolation mode, or if you're protecting something in the filesystem then acquire exclusive access to file(s), etc.